# How to create an /opt partition on an existing installation without loosing data?

Tags: debian, partition, hard-disk, lvm, resize2fs

I've shrinked my /home from 2.7TB to 100G, I've extended /root, /usr, /tmp and /var but I have been looking for a way to create an /opt partition for 3 hours now, and can't find it.

The setup is 3TB luks encrypted partition on /dev/sdb3(container)
inside it are my lvm partitions /root, /usr, /tmp, /var and /home in a Debian Wheezy system.

I used `lvreduce`, `lvextend`, `e2fsck` and `resize2fs` from a booted live cd to change to current partitions. With directions from tutorials and webpages, like [this](http://blog.shadypixel.com/how-to-shrink-an-lvm-volume-safely/) is one.

How do I create an /opt partition 23G from the unused space on /dev/sdb3?

I've tried this:

```
lvcreate -L 23G -n opt Group
```

I don't understand this enough to find the right command, here is the output:

```
/dev/group/opt: not found: device not cleared
Aborting: Failed to wipe start of new LV
```

EDIT #1

Here is `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 30005929282016 bytes

Device Boot       start          end           Blocks     Id system
/dev/sdb1           1            4294967295   2147483647+ ee  GPT

Disk /dev/mapper/crypt1: 3000.3 GB 3000332451840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364769 cylinders, total 58600024320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/0 size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/group-root: 5716MB, 5716836352 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/group-usr: 105,6 GB

Disk /dev/mapper/group-var: 10.5 GB

Disk /dev/mapper/group-swap 8048MB

Disk /dev/mapper/group-tmp 7914MB

Disk /dev/mapper/goup-home 107.4GB
```

Here is `parted /dev/sdb print devices`:

```
/dev/sdb (3001GB)
/dev/mapper/group-tmp (7915MB)
/dev/mapper/group-swap (8049MB)
/dev/mapper/group-home (107GB)
/dev/mapper/group-var (10.5GB)
/dev/mapper/group-usr (106GB)
/dev/mapper/group-root (5717MB)
/dev/mapper/crypt1 (3000GB)
```

Here is `parted /dev/sdb print free`:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 5128/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  start         end      Size         File system   Name   Flags
        17.4kb      1049kb    1031kb         Free space
1       1049kb      2097kb    1049kb                         bios_grub
2       2097kb      258MB     256MB          ext2
3       258MB       3001GB    3000GB
        3001GB      3001GB    466kb          Free space
```

EDIT #2

Here is `vgdisplay`:

```
---- Volume group -----
VG Name           Group
SystemID
Format             lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No 18
VG Access       read/write
VG Status       resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                6
Open LV               0
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size             2.73 TiB
PE Size             4.00 MiB
Total PE            715334
Alloc PE / Size     58461 / 228.36 GiB
Free PE / Size      656873 / 2.51 TiB
VG UUID             239082309572039572039
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious. You say /dev/sdb3 is LUKS encrypted, but not what the LUKS container actually contains. Is that part of the LVM setup? Or is it currently not used for anything at all?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You have to excuse my little-know but I don't fully understand lvm yet. But as I understand it there is sdb which has sdb3 which is encrypted and inside that is my lvm with these partitions, where I want to add an /opt partition to lvm. If I shrink my /home from 2.7TB to 100G there should be alot of free space inside this sdb3. Or maybe I'm just rambling.

Comment: So /dev/sdb3 is a LUKS container which in turn holds your LVM container (within which you created the LVs for various file systems), correct?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, when I accessed the partitions, I used that device with cryptsetup/luksOpen to get access to the volume group.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Hope my new edit clarifies.

Comment: Do you mean `lvcreate --name opt --size 23Gi /dev/group && mkfs -t ext4 -L opt /dev/group/opt` ?

Comment: @roaima I was editing when you commented and that similar to what I tried. I put it in my original question.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the full verbose output of vgdisplay for the group volume group.

Comment: [Google](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124615) suggests that adding `-Z n` to the `lvcreate` command might make the problem go away. If that fails please re-run the `lvcreate` command with a triple verbose flag, `lvcreate -vvv ...`

Comment: @mdpc I've added vgdisplay output.

Comment: Ahh....asked for the verbose output....vgdisplay -v group

Comment: @roaima It worked with `-Z n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent answer is to run these two commands

```
lvcreate --name opt --size 23Gi group
mkfs -t ext4 -L opt /dev/group/opt
```

However, via the comments thread it became apparent that `lvcreate` threw an error message,

```
/dev/group/opt: not found: device not cleared
Aborting: Failed to wipe start of new LV
```

A [search on Google](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124615) finds that this is a known error, and the suggested workaround is to avoid zeroing the first part of the LV by using `lvcreate --zero n ...`.

I've done [some more investigation](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/12/msg00407.html) and it appears that `lvcreate` will work fine once `udev` is restarted (either via a system reboot or with `udevadm reload`). I would surmise that the `/dev/{volumegroup}` node is simply not being created, and so `lvcreate` can't find it.

*(Answer extracted from the comments thread)*